# How to split text in each row when getting the data from kafka topic?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-streams

I retrive data from a kafka topic. After converting the data into a dataframe with 10 columns, i choose 1 one of the columns. i want to split string in each row so i can convert words to their pronounciation. evrything seems to be ok, but the only problem that i have is that i can't run split method on a row.?

here is my code

```
   val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "rocket-01.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094")
            .option("subscribe", "k-news") 
            .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
            .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL")
            .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
            .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=" " password="";").load()

val newsStringDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

val newsSchema = StructType( Array(
     StructField("_c0",StringType,true),
     StructField("id",StringType,true),
     StructField("title",StringType,true),
     StructField("publication",StringType,true),
     StructField("author",StringType,true),
     StructField("date",StringType,true),
     StructField("year",StringType,true),
     StructField("month",StringType,true),
     StructField("url",StringType,true),
     StructField("content",StringType,true)))


val lines = Source.fromFile("/Project/symbols/cmudict.dict").getLines()
val res = lines.map { line =>line.split(" ", 2) match { case Array(a, b) => a -> b }}.toMap


val newsDF = newsStringDF.select(from_json(col("value"),
newsSchema).as("data")).select("data.*")
val titleColumn = newsDF.select("title").as[String].foreach( message => 
message.split(" ").toList.map { s =>if(res.get(s).isDefined) {res(s)} else 
{s}}.mkString(" ")).toDF("title") 

val streaming = titleColumn.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("append").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).start().awaitTermination()
```

The output should be something like this:
i get message(string from title column) from my kafka-topic and I replace it with another string. "I like football" --> "I like ˈfo͝otˌbôl" and write the message to the console with .writeStream

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show minimal code to reproduce this? (Including schema definition, sample input data, definition of variable `res`). Ideally also provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: would be good to get a sample input and output data set and a few more lines of code snippet that you have to get a clear view of the problem.

Comment: Now i update my question and tried to explain how the output should look like. thanks for anyhelp in advance.

Comment: Could you show me your spark-submit command?  i am working on a similar problem and i am unsure how to configure spark-submit

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that a `Dataframe` is really just a `Dataset[Row]`. When working with simple types (and even some custom case classes) it's easy to convert between a typed `Dataset`, and an untyped `Dataframe`. In this particular case, it should be as easy as:

```
val titleColumn = newsDF
  .select("title")
  .as[String]
  .map( message => message.split(" ").toList.map { s =>
    if(res.get(s).isDefined) {res(s)} else {s}}.mkString(" ")
  )
  .toDF("title")
```

The extra lines `.as[String]` converts your `Dataframe` to a `Dataset[String]`, and the `.toDF("title")` converts it back. This allows your map to operate on `String`s instead of `Row`s. Since this is a tranformation, you'll also want to use `.map` instead of `.foreach` on the `Dataset`.

One other options is to retrieve the title `String` from the `Row` and split on that:

```
message.getAs[String]("title").split(" ")
```

I'm not sure which approach is more efficient. Here is a tested sample:

```
val df = Seq("aa 11", "bb 22", "cc 33", "dd 44").toDF("title")

val res = Map("aa" -> "AA", "bb" -> "BB", "cc" -> "CC", "dd" -> "DD")

df.as[String].map(m => {
  m.split(" ").toList.map(s => {
    if(res.get(s).isDefined) res(s) else s    
  }).mkString(" ")
}).toDF("title").show()
```

Which results in:

```
+-----+
|title|
+-----+
|AA 11|
|BB 22|
|CC 33|
|DD 44|
+-----+
```

Comment: unfortunatly neither way worked for me. I tried the first method and i get an error: overloaded method value foreach with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction[String])Unit <and>
  (f: String => Unit)Unit. And when i tried the other method i get almost the same error:

Comment: Whoops! I didn't notice the `.foreach` the first time. You'll want to use a `.map` instead, since this is a transformation. I believe the error is related to the fact that your anonymous function is returning a `List[String]` instead of a `Unit`.

Comment: See the edits, where I include a tested sample block of code.

Comment: Yes, it worked once i chaned foreach with map. so this part of the code is not a problem anymore :), but got an error when i tried to writeStream to the console.   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416). Tryed to search what can cuz this error, but still didn't find out

Comment: That error happens when you are referencing a variable inside of your anonymous function which can not be serialized. The `.writeStream` method is your Action, which is what causes the transformation code to be leading up to it to actually execute. The error is likely happening before that. Generally, you see this unserializable variable inside of anonymous functions which get distributed to the cluster (`map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, etc. against a dataframe). A lot of times it's an instance representing something like a database connection, which can't be moved to other nodes.